# DeleteById not working for Cascade deletes in Micronaut

Tags: java, database, jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have following Database structure:

Multiple columns in MainType table can refer to entries in Type1 and Type2. E.g. column2 and column3 refer to different entries in Type2 table.

[image]

and implementation is as follows:

**Entities:**

```
@MappedEntity
//Lombok Annotations
public record MainType(

@Id UUID id,
@Nullable @Relation(value = KIND.ONE_TO_ONE, cascade = Cascade.ALL) Type1 column1, 
@Nullable @Relation(value = KIND.ONE_TO_ONE, cascade = Cascade.ALL) Type2 column2, 
@Nullable @Relation(value = KIND.ONE_TO_ONE, cascade = Cascade.ALL) Type2 column3) {}

@MappedEntity
//Lombok Annotations
public class Type1 {
  @Id @Autopopulated UUID id,
  @Nullable String value, 
}

@MappedEntity
//Lombok Annotations
public class Type2 {
  @Id @Autopopulated UUID id,
  @Nullable int value, 
}
```

**Repositories:**

**MainTypeRepository**

```
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.Oracle)
public interface MainTypeRepository extends PageableRepository<MainType, UUID> {

 @Override
 @Join(value= type1, type = Type.LEFT_FETCH)
 @Join(value= type2, type = Type.LEFT_FETCH)
 Optional<MainType> findById(UUID id);

 @Override
 @Join(value= type1, type = Type.LEFT_FETCH)
 @Join(value= type2, type = Type.LEFT_FETCH)
 void deleteById(UUID id);
}
```

**Type1Repository**

```
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.Oracle)
public interface Type1Repository extends CrudRepository<Type1, UUID> {}
```

**Type2Repository**

```
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.Oracle)
public interface Type2Repository extends CrudRepository<Type2, UUID> {}
```

My problem is that when I execute mainTypeRepository.deleteById(id) it does not delete the entries in Type1 and Type2 Tables. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Micronaut Data JDBC doesn’t support cascading delete.

Comment: Is overriding delete method with a native query, the best option here? Is there a length limit for the query string?

Comment: You can have multiple custom query methods to delete the children and one default method ‘deleteByIdAndChildren’ where you would call those extra methods delete the children first and then the parent.